# How to display a list of class objects in a Collection View?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, maui

I want to display a list (observable collection) of BleDevice type in my view. I'm using mvvm pattern in .net maui (.net 7).

Model:

```
public class BleDevice
    {
        public BleDevice(){}
        public BleDevice(string name, string mac) 
        {
            Name = name;
            MacAddress = mac;
        }
        public string Name {  get; set; }
        public string MacAddress { get; set; }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public partial class MainViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
        
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            devices = new ObservableCollection<BleDevice>();
            devices.Add(new BleDevice("Mystronics Winder", "00:00:00:00:00"));
            devices.Add(new BleDevice("Living Room TV", "25:e7:aa:05:84"));
        }

        [ObservableProperty]
        ObservableCollection<BleDevice> devices;
    }
```

View(xaml): **(Edited)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Model"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate  x:DataType="{model:BleDevice}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding MacAddress}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Error:
`XFC0045   Binding: Property "Name" not found on "MauiApp2.ViewModel.MainViewModel".    MauiApp2   \source\repos\MauiApp2\MauiApp2\View\MainPage.xaml`

Why it does recognize the `"{Binding Devices}"` but not `"{Binding Name}"` and `"{Binding MacAddress}"`?

Comment: you either need to add a `DataType` attribute to your `DataTemplate` or remove the one you already have elsewhere in your page

Comment: An unrelated note, the `Devices` property doesn't need to have the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute as it's an `ObservableCollection`. The `ObservableCollection` will notify the UI of any changes in the collection (adding, removing, etc) by itself.

Comment: if you remove the attribute then they will need to explicitly make it a public property

Comment: @Jason is this correct? `<DataTemplate  x:DataType="{model:BleDevice}">` I still getting the same error.

Comment: No.  Look at how the other `DataType` you have on your page is formatted

Comment: @Jason the datatype of the main contentPage is defined like this `xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:MainViewModel"` to access the viewmodel. (ps: sorry I'm a noob developer in .net)

Comment: look at the two different `DataType` declarations.  What is different about the one that does NOT work?

Comment: @Jason It was a typo mistake. thanks for helping anyway :)

Comment: You can also refer to the official doc about [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data). It could be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ViewModel** Remove the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute and change to this:

```
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Devices = new ObservableCollection<BleDevice>();
            Devices.Add(new BleDevice("Mystronics Winder", "00:00:00:00:00"));
            Devices.Add(new BleDevice("Living Room TV", "25:e7:aa:05:84"));
        }

      public ObservableCollection<BleDevice> Devices { get; set; }
    }
```

**View(xaml)** Remove the `x:DataType="xxx"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:MauiApp2.Model"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding MacAddress}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```